# unable to convert string date in Format yyyyMMddHHmmss to DateTime dart

Tags: dart, flutter

i have a string containing date in format yyyyMMddHHmmss (e.g.) (20180626170555)  and i am using following code to convert it into date time

```
dateTimeFromString(json['dateTime'], "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

exception is:

```
FormatException: Trying to read MM from 20180623130424 at position 14
```

what can be the reason?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`intl DateFormat` can't cope with your input string as it doesn't have any separators. The whole string gets consumed as the year. However `DateTime.parse` does cope with this (nearly). It happens to expect precisely the format you have (again, nearly).

One of the acceptable styles to `parse` is `20120227T132700`, which just differs by the `T` date/time separator.

Try this:

```
String date = '20180626170555';
String dateWithT = date.substring(0, 8) + 'T' + date.substring(8);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateWithT);
```

Answer (score 150):

`DateTime.parse("string date here")` accept some formatted string only. Check below examples of accepted strings.

- `"2012-02-27 13:27:00"`
- `"2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z"`
- `"2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z"`
- `"20120227 13:27:00"`
- `"20120227T132700"`
- `"20120227"`
- `"+20120227"`
- `"2012-02-27T14Z"`
- `"2012-02-27T14+00:00"`
- `"-123450101 00:00:00 Z"`: in the year -12345.
- `"2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500"`: Same as `"2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"`

**=> String to DateTime**

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(savedDateString);
```

**=> DateTime to String**

```
String date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now());
```

> Reference links:
>
> - Use `intl` for `DateFormat` from flutter package (https://pub.dev/packages/intl)
> - DateTime.parse() => https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Answer (score 36):

to convert from `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` to `'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'`

```
date = '2021-01-26T03:17:00.000000Z';
DateTime parseDate =
    new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(date);
var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseDate.toString());
var outputFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');
var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
print(outputDate)
```

> output
> 01/26/2021 03:17 AM

Answer (score 24):

You can use DateFormat to parse a DateTime from string to an object

```
// With en_US locale by default
var newDateTimeObj = new DateFormat().add_yMd().add_Hms().parse("7/10/1996 10:07:23")
// with a defined format
var newDateTimeObj2 = new DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("10/02/2000 15:13:09")
```

Check the doc [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

Answer (score 14):

**The Easient way convert a string into Date format is**

```
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02')); // 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('20200102')); // 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('-12345-03-04')); // -12345-03-04 00:00:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02 07')); // 2020-01-02 07:00:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07')); // 2020-01-02 07:00:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12')); // 2020-01-02 07:12:00.000
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12:50')); // 2020-01-02 07:12:50.000
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12:50Z')); // 2020-01-02 07:12:50.000Z
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12:50+07')); // 2020-01-02 00:12:50.000Z
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12:50+0700')); // 2020-01-02 00:12:50.00
  print(DateTime.parse('2020-01-02T07:12:50+07:00')); // 2020-01-02 00:12:50.00
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html), you need Single `M` to `month in year` :

```
dateTimeFromString(json['dateTime'], "yMdHms")
```

Comment: The dart documentation is not very clear ! : **Number**: the minimum number of digits. Shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount (e.g. if "m" produces "6", "mm" produces "06").

Comment: your solution gives: FormatException: Trying to read M from 20180623130424 at position 14

Answer (score 2):

Basic information about how to convert String to Date and Date to string in flutter. Look at below link

https://quickstartflutterdart.blogspot.com/2018/10/how-to-convert-string-to-date-and-date.html

Might be it will be helped for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
String startdate1="10/31/2022";
String endate1="11/02/2022";


DateTime start = new DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(startdate1); 
DateTime end = new DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(enddate1);
DateTime s = DateTime(start.year, start.month, start.day);
DateTime to = DateTime(end.year, end.month, end.day);
int day= (to.difference(s).inHours / 24).round()+1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i did something like this (using the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package)

```
final date = '7/10/1996';
final month = DateFormat.LLLL().format(DateTime.parse(date));
```

`LLLL` in the code above is date format skeleton meaning 'stand alone month', other date formatter is presented [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date and time string in a specific format, you can convert it to a DateTime object by using the parse() method. For example, if you have a string that contains “12/03/2019 9:45 AM”, you can use the parse() method to convert it to a DateTime object like this:

var dateTimeString = “12/03/2019 9:45 AM”;
var dateTimeObject = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString);

print(dateTimeObject); // 12/03/2019 09:45:00.000
The parse() method is very versatile and can handle a variety of different formats. If your string doesn’t follow a strict format, you can use tryParse() instead. This method will return null if it fails to parse the string.
for detail click here
https://mycodingwork.com/flutter-convert-string-to-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

Without using any package you can use:

```
DateTime tempDate =  DateTime.parse(date);
```

Examples of accepted Formats:

```
"2012-02-27"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z"
"2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z"
"20120227 13:27:00"
"20120227T132700"
"20120227"
"+20120227"
"2012-02-27T14Z"
"2012-02-27T14+00:00"
"-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.
"2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"
```

This method accepts out-of-range component values and interprets them as overflows into the next larger component. For example, "2020-01-42" will be parsed as 2020-02-11, because the last valid date in that month is 2020-01-31, so 42 days is interpreted as 31 days of that month plus 11 days into the next month.