# Dart / Flutter: I am trying to convert a String to a Date but getting an Exception

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, there are some situations where the `date` field in the JSON is invalid. Instead of displaying "Invalid date" I would like to display another field called `timestamp`. This field, however, is at this format: `20200518100014`. I would like to convert that to `May 18, 2020`.

I have not been successful and this is the latest code I have

```
String processDate(data) {
    var timeStamp = DateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse(data.timestamp.toString());
    return data.date == 'Invalid date' ? timeStamp : data.date;
}
```

This causes the following error:

[image]

**How can I fix this issue to display the date as `May 18, 2020` format instead.**

---

**ANSWER**:

Based on @Lunedor answer below, I was able to create the following solution:

```
String processDate(data) {
    String date = data.timestamp.toString();
    String dateWithT = date.substring(0, 8) + 'T' + date.substring(8);
    String dateTime = DateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(DateTime.parse(dateWithT));

    return data.date == 'Invalid date' ? dateTime : data.date;
}
```

Comment: You are doing a small mistake..it should be..```String processDate(data) {
    return data.date == 'Invalid date' ? DateFormat("mm, dd, yyyy").parse(data.timestamp.toString()) : data.date;
}```..you gave `MMM` instead of `mm`..hope it solves your issue..not sure if it works..just give it a try..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I still get an error: FormatException: Trying to read from 20200518100014 at position 15

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am skipping MMM mistake, check this answer to see what type of strings can be parse as time and date:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988096/12880676

And your case you can use the method in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51063116/12880676).
I am just copy and paste the code:

```
String date = '20180626170555';
String dateWithT = date.substring(0, 8) + 'T' + date.substring(8);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateWithT);
```

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to create a solution. See question for solution. 

BTW: MMM is the only thing I could find that formats the month with 3 letters (May, Feb, Jun, etc). Why is that wrong?

Comment: MMM isn't wrong actually just MM is more common so if it's by your choice there is no wrong to use it of course.